# How to display validation messages in Windows Phone 8

Tags: unit-testing, validation, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I want to display Windows Phone 8 page validations in an elegant and unit testable manner.  I am thinking about using DataBinding rather than MessageBox modal messages.  What is the standard or best practice for Windows Phone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the Telerik controls style, or use them anyway, they have a TextBox with validation and I think is a simple binding to an errors collection. You can download the Telerik Examples apps to test it in your phone and see if you like the implementation.